# Filter a list on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to Filter a list on Multiple columns. I know I can loop thru the list collection and filter the records, is there any better way?

My first criteria is  `colA !=  “X”`  and if `colA == “Y”`than check for colB value for this type only.

I have to allow all values on colA except “X” and `if  ColA == “Y” && colB == “T”`  ( I check colB value only `if ColA == “Y”)`  I am not able to write this.

Basically if ColA == “X” then don’t allow and if ColA == “Y” then check for colB value and filter depending on the value. Allow rest of all ColA values.

```
Accounts = Accounts.Where(acc => acc.ColA != “X” || ??).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this *should* work *if* I am understanding your question correctly.

```
Accounts.Where(acc => !(acc.ColA == "X" || (acc.ColA == "Y" && acc.ColB == "T"))).ToArray();
```

However, I think this is more readable:

```
Accounts
    .Where(acc => !(acc.ColA == "X"))
    .Where(acc => !(acc.ColA == "Y" && acc.ColB == "T"))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: 32bitkid -   Superb, awesome answer! It worked …. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
string columnBValue = "T";
Accounts = Accounts.Where(acc => 
                      acc.ColA != “X” 
                      && 
                      (x.ColA != "Y" || 
                      (x.ColA == "Y" && x.ColB == columnBValue)))
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: NO this doesn't work as I said in above post I already tried so it only allows where x.ColA == "Y" && x.ColB == columnBValue all other ColA values are getting disregarded which I don't want. I want all colA values except X and if value is Y then check for additional criteria othewise don't check just select that value

Comment: Right, just check the last version