# Split List into Multiple Lists by Criteria c#

Tags: c#

I have a List consisting of the Following Objects

```
List<Person> PersonList
```

The Person class

```
class Person
{
  public int PersonId{get;set;}
  public string PersonName{get;set;
  public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

---

I have another List that contains a List of Ages that I am interested in, like 12, 14, 16, 24 etc.

```
List<int> AgeList
```

I want to compare the Age of the `PersonList` with the ages found in `AgeList` and IF found, store it in a separate Lists based upon each group. For example People belonging to Age 12 should be in a different List, Age 14 in a different List and So on..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter a list on multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095487/filter-a-list-on-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 1):

This is some quick code for you, without LINQ. First you create new list of type `Person`, then loop over your Person list, and for every person you check if age is the same as one in your age list.

```
List<Person> finalList=new List<Person>();
foreach (var a in PersonList)
{
    foreach (var b in AgeList)
    {
        if (a.Age==b)
        {
            finalList.Add(a);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could put a break inside the `if` as well to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Person> data = new List<Person>();
List<int> ages = new List<int>();
List<Person> result = data.Where(p => ages.Contains(p.Age)).ToList();
```

Comment: I would want to Store the matched records for any age group in a separate List.

Comment: Yes. `List<Person> result` is the separate List. Or do you mean something else ?

Comment: I mean a separate List for people belonging to each age group. For e.g a separate list of people aged 12, and so on

Comment: ok. Got you. 
`List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
            List<int> ageList = new List<int>();
            Dictionary<int, List<Person>> seperateLists = new Dictionary<int, List<Person>>();
            foreach (var person in personList){foreach (var age in ageList){if(person.Age == age){if (seperateLists.ContainsKey(age)){var lists = seperateLists[age];lists.Add(person);seperateLists[age] = lists;
                        }else{var lists = new List<Person>();lists.Add(person);seperateLists.Add(age, lists);}}}}`

Removed formatting due to lack of space in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ solution:

```
List<Person> personAgeList = PersonList.Where(p => AgeList.Contains(p.Age)).ToList();
```